# How Can I Pythonically pass complex arguments to functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, oop

I have a SOAP web service I have to work with, and one of the commands it supports is a "SQL like" query where I input a select, from, and where statements. I think the "where" clause will be most demonstrative of what I'm trying to do so here:

```
def sql_soap(tablename, where):
   sql_where = [soap_object(where_statement) for where_statement in where]
   return query

sql_soap('student',where=[{'Condition':'=','Field':'Subject','Value':'Calculus'}])
```

Basically, the way I've thought to do this is to package a list of where-clause dictionaries. But the dictionaries should always have the same keys. Is there a way to define this type in the function definition? I don't want kwargs or args because I know in advance the data structure.

One thing I looked at was

```
def sql_soap(tablename, *, where):
```

Apparently this is only available in newer versions of Python (which I have) but my understanding is the where clause after this is expecting a dictionary, and I want a list of dictionaries.

Generally speaking how do I define a function argument, when I want a dictionary inside of a list, or something else nested? Is there any way besides a dictionary, that I can get a single function parameter (where) to accept all of the arguments I need to make the SOAP where object?

Comment: The only difference with the second version is that you can't pass `where` positionally. Also your first version doesn't seem to be syntactically valid.

Comment: `where` is just expecting a Python object, no more specific. It doesn't expect a dictionary or a list of dictionaries or anything so specific.

Comment: The only thing you did is specify that `where` can only be used as a keyword argument, so `sql_soap('student', [...])` is not accepted, but `sql_soap('student', where=[...])` *is*.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this helps, but you could use *where to expect an arbitrary amount of args:

```
def sql_soap(tablename, *where):
   sql_where = [soap_object(where_statement) for where_statement in where]
   return query

sql_soap('student',
         {'Condition':'=','Field':'Subject','Value':'Calculus'},
         {'Condition':'=','Field':'Subject2','Value':'Calculus2'},
)
```

One thing you can also do, but you would to have to change probaply a lot of code for that, is use namedtuple instead of dictionaries:

```
from collections import namedtuple

wheretuple = namedtuple("wheretuple", "field condition value")
sql_soap('student', wheretuple("Subject", "=", "Calculus"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified anything about types. The `*` syntax in a function definition only specifies how a caller can provide arguments for the parameters. Parameters before it can be filled with both positional arguments and keyword arguments, those that follow the `*` can only be specified with keyword arguments.

Put differently, the following calls are now legal:

```
sql_soap('student', where=[...])  # one positional, one keyword argument
sql_soap(tablename='student', where=[...])  # two keyword arguments
```

but the following is not:

```
sql_soap('student', [...])  # two positional arguments
```

You'll instead get a `TypeError` exception, `TypeError: sql_soap() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Using `*` in a function definition does not say anything about what type of objects the parameter accepts. You can still pass anything you like to the function call.

Perhaps you got confused with the `*args` and `**kwargs` syntax in function definitions, where those parameters capture *all remaining positional or keyword arguments passed in*, which did not address any of the other parameters. They don't say anything about the argument types *either*; instead they put those remaining argument values in a tuple and dictionary, respectively.

Python does now support [*type hinting*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), but even type hinting will not let you specify what keys to use in a dictionary.

I'd use [*named tuples*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) instead here, together with type hints:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Sequence

class WhereClause(NamedTuple):
    condition: str
    field: str
    value: str


def sql_soap(tablename: str, where: Sequence[WhereClause]):
    ...
```

This lets the type checker know that the `where` argument *must* be a sequence type (like a list), that contains only `WhereClause` instances. And those instances will have specific attributes.

Anytime you want to use any of the `WhereClause` instances, you can use attributes to get at the contents, so `whereclause.condition` and `whereclause.value`.